# Where does vscode store the webviews layout info?

Tags: vscode-extensions

When we open a new workspace in vscode, all the websviews and layouts will be cleared.

I am thinking of implementing an extension that allow vscode to save / restore webviews and layouts via serialization of the webviews and layouts info.  In order to do that, the first question that i have is where does vscode serialize the webview and layout info?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know which layout info you mean. The editor groups layout is automatically saved and restored. Webviews are embedded iframes with no implicit layout. Once VS Code is closed all webviews are gone.

Comment: Layout info as in how the webviews are laid side-by-side or bottom, eg. https://dev.to/vscode/-vscode-grid-editor-layout-is-here-b6a

Yes, you are right that the editor groups layout are automatically saved and restored.  Do you know where vscode save the groups layout?  if we have access to the file storing the layout group, we can restore various groups layout instead of only the "last-saved" one.

Comment: No, I don't know where this is stored. You could scan the source code of vscode to figure that out. But I doubt there are multiple versions of the layout stored. I believe only the last one is actually kept.